# PHP .DS. on godaddy

Tags: php

Thanks in advance for any help.
i have spent a lot of time trying to find the solution and i don't usually ask for help.
The server is on Godaddy.com
this all works great on my local host.

```
 <?php require_once("../includes/initialize.php"); ?>

// this is the initialize.php file
<?php

// Define the core paths
// Define them as absolute paths to make sure that require_once works as expected

// DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is a PHP pre-defined constant
// (\ for Windows, / for Unix)
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : 
define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'webroot'.DS.'photo_gallery');

defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS."includes");

// load config file first
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS."config.php");

// load basic functions next so that everything after can use them
 require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'functions.php');

// load core objects
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'session.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database_object.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'pagination.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'phpMailer'.DS.'class.phpmailer.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'phpMailer'.DS.'class.smtp.php');

// load database-related classes
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'user.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'photograph.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'comment.php');

?>
```

this is the path in the upper right hand corner of the file manager on godaddy.
webroot / photo_gallery / includes / initialize.php

all files are in the includes folder

here is the error :)

Warning: require_once(/webroot/photo_gallery/includes/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/43/7465643/html/photo_gallery/includes/initialize.php on line 16

well the site wont let me answer my own question so here is the answer.

Thanks Quixrick here is the working code:

```
<?php
$webroot = "home/content/43/7465643/html/";

// Define the core paths
// Define them as absolute paths to make sure that require_once works as expected

// DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is a PHP pre-defined constant
// (\ for Windows, / for Unix)
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : 
define('SITE_ROOT', DS.$webroot.DS.'photo_gallery');

defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');

// load config file first
require_once(LIB_PATH .DS.'config.php');

// load basic functions next so that everything after can use them
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'functions.php');

// load core objects
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'session.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database_object.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'pagination.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'PHPMailer'.DS.'class.phpmailer.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'PHPMailer'.DS.'class.smtp.php');

// load database-related classes
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'user.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'photograph.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'comment.php');

?>
```

...Programing is very complex but most of the time is spent figuring out what you did wrong.

well at least for me anyway :)

Comment: It's pretty clear isn't it?  That file doesn't exist.  Also, you can use `/` on both Windows and *nix.

Comment: but the file does exist and its in the includes folder. all if those files are in the includes folder. I cant just change the .DS. to / because there are methods that use the .DS. and without defining it i will have to write the whole thing over.

Comment: Do you have to install php on godaddy or is it there automatically. I set up a new account the other day and I need next to get my php to access the database mySQL on the server. www.jamesbond.ws is the site.

Answer (score 2):

Your web root is being set to `webroot` instead of `/home/content/43/7465643/html`.  Probably you need to use a variable when setting this line:

```
define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'webroot'.DS.'photo_gallery');
```

Maybe like this?

```
define('SITE_ROOT', DS.$webroot.DS.'photo_gallery');
```

Or if it's a constant, take out the quotes around it:

```
define('SITE_ROOT', DS.webroot.DS.'photo_gallery');
```

Comment: More like OP's building a web path, but using it in a filesystem context. Unless the site's webroot really IS at the root of the file system, it should really be `/path/to/site/document/webroot/....` instead

Comment: i used the variable $webroot = "home/content/43/7465643/html/"; and got all the way to the phpmailer line before generating an error. it progress:)

Comment: Thanks Quixrick, it works, what a relief. i had the phpMailer folder with lowercase phpmailer and the folder was named upercase PHPMailer so that fixed that. i will post the working code so if anyone else has to spend 2 days trying to figure out godaddys root folder maybe they can save some time and frustration. maybe godaddy should take a look at it so when someone calls they can have an answer. lol